# Check SSAS Version

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, ssas, ssas-2012

We have installed Analysis server 2016 but when we check the version by connecting to SSMS it still shows 2014 version. Are there any settings that need to be done after installing 2016 version?

Comment: You might be checking the SSMS version, to check the SSAS version go to SSMS -- connect to SSAS instance --> reports -> standard reports --> General and there would be the version for you.

Comment: I checked it shows 2014 version. I installed 2016 version and it doesn't seem to update the version

Comment: How did you install it? Did you install it with the other(2014) instance still there? In that case you might still be connecting to the 2014 instance. You should specificly connect to the 2016 instance.

Comment: Do we need to remove 2014 and then install 2016 ?